# iPhone PopUp RGB colors

Tags: iphone, objective-c, rgb

I am presenting a UIView with an animation that takes half of the screen. I've seen it in many apps but could not find the appropriate RGB colors:

iOS uses it for example in "contacts":

http://img98.imageshack.us/img98/9402/image001u.png

I'm trying with :

```
bottomLayer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:80.0/255.0 green:86.0/255.0 blue:97.0/255.0 alpha:1] CGColor];
```

but it's all whitey.

If anyone could get how this popup is designed...

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to look at [UIActionSheet](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html). It will create the view for you and have the proper animations.  Very easy to use.

You just need to implement the `UIActionSheetDelegate` Delegate method.

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UIActionSheetDelegate>
```

And then to make the action sheet:

```
UIActionSheet *choice = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"" 
                                                    delegate:self 
                                           cancelButtonTitle:@"Annuler" 
                                      destructiveButtonTitle:nil 
                                           otherButtonTitles:@"Prendre une photo",@"Choisir une photo",nil];
[choice showInView:self.view];
```

And that will call:

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

Which is just like the UIAlertView.

Comment: +1 Beat me to it. (And then you added loads more detail.) :-)

Comment: @middaparka: I accidentally put UIAlertSheet first. :) Had to look it up in my code before remembering the proper name. Thanks for the +1.

Comment: Thanks Rayan and middiparka ! So easy to use!

Answer (score 3):

There is a great utility called "DigitalColor Meter" located in Applications/Utilities/ that can get the RGB for anything on your screen. I find this incredibly helpful.

Answer (score 2):

This the standard UIActionSheet background. See the [UIActionSheet Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more information.

Incidentally, the NavBar sample code (linked from within the Related sample code section of the above class reference), is quite a good demo of such things.

Comment: Thanks Rayan and middiparka !

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the color to a normal view and wonder why its white then the answer is you don't have to `CGColor` it

```
bottomLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:80.0/255.0 green:86.0/255.0 blue:97.0/255.0 alpha:1];
```